# Отображение всех организаций на карте из категории

Tags: организация

подскажите, можно ли организовать на своём сайте список нужных категорий и вывод по ним организаций на карте. то есть поиск не конкретных организаций, а например, просмотр всех аптек, или всех салонов красоты

Comment: ну вроде никто не запрещает, так что да, можно :)

Comment: а как же это сделать? например в на яндекс картах категории организаций можно найти, прям отображается "найдено столько-то организаций", а вот в примере апи карт категории не находятся через поиск.